# How to make an Array Loop for Pivot Table filtering faster?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

As follows is what I currently use to filter a pivot table but it takes a really long time, and I use this format for more than one pivot table. So, I was wondering if anyone knows how to make this more efficient and faster?

```
Dim FilterArr() As Variant
Dim PTItm As PivotItem

FiterArr = Array("10000000", "100000001") 'Example, my array has more than 80 numbers can't show due to confidentiality


For Each PTItm In irccTable.PivotFields("Cost Center").PivotItems
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(PTItm.Caption, FiterArrIrcc, 0)) Then ' check if current item is        not in the filter array
        PTItm.Visible = True
    Else
        PTItm.Visible = False
   End If
Next PTItm
```

I didn't try anything, don't know what direction to go.

Comment: Have you set [Application.ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) to False? Do you need the actual pivot tables to be filtered or a range with the resulting data will do? For the latter you might try to store the data in an array and then filter it instead.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey I do need the actual pivot to be filtered. But, I didn't have Application ScreenUpdating set to false,  that cut in half my running time. Thank you! Do you know if you can batch filter a pivot table, instead of having to go through each and everyone?

Comment: You are welcome. Is the cut enouth? There are [more tricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions) that might help a code or an Excel file itself to run faster, just so you know.

Comment: You could try first calling `ShowAllItems` and then only hide the items not in the array?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm sure what your saying; however, there hundreds of items in the filter. So, I don't know if targetig the items not in the array would make it faster.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey I looked through the tricks, it helped but it still takes a while. And, as the year goes by I foresee it taking much more time.

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.pivot-table.com/2022/04/06/faster-pivot-table-refresh-in-excel-macros/

Answer (score 1):

So Application.ScreenUpdating = False, cut my run time in half; however, I just ended up outside of excel vba creating another column on the raw data table with a categorical numbers and then grouping the different groups of numbers under different categories and such the macro only needs to go through an infinitely smaller list of numbers to filter. Thanks to @Evil Blue Monkey and @Tim Williams for their help!